# Displaying size of a file [C]

Tags: c, file, ftell

I'm making a simple sockets program to send a text file or a picture file over to another socket connected to a port. However, I want to also send the size of the file over to the client socket so that it knows how many bytes to receive.

I also want to implement something where I can send a certain number of bytes instead of the file itself. For example, if a file I wanted to send was 14,003 bytes and I felt like sending 400 bytes, then only 400 bytes would be sent.

I am implementing something like this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     FILE *fp;
     char* file = "text.txt";
     int offset = 40;
     int sendSize = 5;
     int fileSize = 0;

     if ((fp = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL) {
         printf("Error: Cannot open the file!\n");
         return 1;
     } else {
         /* Seek from offset into the file */
         //fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
         fseek(fp, offset, sendSize + offset); // seek to sendSize
         fileSize = ftell(fp); // get current file pointer
         //fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // seek back to beginning of file
     }

     printf("The size is: %d", fileSize);
 }
```

`offset` is pretty much going to go 40 bytes into the file and then send whatever `sendSize` bytes over to the other program.

I keep getting an output of `0` instead of `5`. Any reason behind this?

Comment: Have a look at `sendfile` (e.g. look at `man sendfile`) in `#include <sys/sendfile.h>`, it does just what you are doing with the offset/transfer.

Comment: Your `whence` is not right, e.g. `fseek(fp, sendSize, SEEK_SET);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sounds good. However, if I wanted to use this method instead of `sendfile`, would I be able to? I think everything looks right in terms of setting sizes.

Comment: Sure, there is not a problem doing it. If the files are large, `sendfile` will be a factor of 5 faster due to the transfer being done in kernel-space without needing user-space. But there is nothing wrong coding it the way you are. You will want to use `write` or `frwite` to do the actual transfer.

Comment: if (linux) http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/2/stat/

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you sir.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your Seek does not work due to the 3rd parameter:
try to seek with
`(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);`

as he will try to use the number sendSize+Offset as the "origin" constant, it will be compared to the 3 constant values as below (it is 0, 1 or 2) and as nothing compares it seem to return 0 all time.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

Parameters

stream, offset, origin
    Position used as reference for the offset. It is specified by one of the following constants defined in  exclusively to be used as arguments for this function:
    Constant    Reference position
    SEEK_SET    Beginning of file
    SEEK_CUR    Current position of the file pointer
    SEEK_END    End of file

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    char* file = "text.txt";
    int offset = 40;
    int sendSize = 5;
    int fileSize = 0;

    if ((fp = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Cannot open the file!\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        fileSize = ftell(fp);
    }

    printf("The size is: %d", fileSize);
}
```

Comment: Correct. But, that isn't what I want to do with sending information over to the client socket. I simply want to go `offset` bytes into the file and then send `sendSize` bytes from `offset` over.

Comment: Don't forget to reset the seeker back!

Comment: Curious that code used `0L`, when `0` would work, yet used `int fileSize` instead of matching the return type of `ftell()`.

Answer (score 1):

The fseek() to the end, then ftell() method is a reasonably portable way of getting the size of a file, but not guaranteed to be correct. It won't transparently handle newline / carriage return conversions, and as a result, the standard doesn't actually guarantee that the return from ftell() is useful for any purpose other than seeking to the same position.

The only portable way is to read the file until data runs out and keep a count of bytes. Or stat() the file using the (non-ANSI) Unix standard function.

Answer (score 1):

You may be opening the file in text mode as [Windows can open a file in text mode even without the `"t"` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx).

And you can't use `ftell()` to get the size of a file opened in text mode.  Per **7.21.9.4  The `ftell` function** of the C Standard:

> **For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information**, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file
>   position indicator for the stream  to  its  position  at  the  time 
>   of  the `ftell` call;  **the  difference  between  two  such return
>   values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of
>   characters written or read**.

Even if it does return the "size" of the file, the translation to "text" may changed the actual number of bytes read.

It's also not portable or standard-conforming to use `fseek()` to find the end of a binary file.  Per **7.21.9.2  The
`fseek`
function**:

> A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a
>   `whence` value of `SEEK_END`.